# OPTIONS request gets a "401 Unauthorized" response

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, cors, symfony4

I crafted an API with Symfony 4 that uses a custom token verification. I tested the API on Postman and everything works perfectly, now I want to use the API using jQuery and fetch all the data , but in the browser, I'm facing CORS issues like below:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/reports' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Here is my server-side API:

I've implemented a `CORSEventSubscriber` to allow the CORS like below :

```
class CORSSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

/**
 * @var TokenStorageInterface
 */
private $tokenStorage;

public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    $responseHeaders = $event->getResponse()->headers;
    $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'x-auth-token, content-type');
    $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET');
}

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        KernelEvents::RESPONSE => 'onKernelResponse',
    ];
}
```

This is the action that I'm calling in the controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/reports",name="reports",methods={"GET","OPTIONS"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 * @throws  Exception
 */
function getReports(Request $request){

return new JsonResponse('test', Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);

}
```

I tried consuming the `API` like this

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        authenticate().then(function (data) {
           // the promise resolve the token and data.token output the correct value
           $.ajax({
               url:'http://localhost:8000/api/reports',
               type: 'GET',
                headers: {'X-Auth-Token' : data.token },
               success: function (data) {
                   //append data to your app
                   console.log(data);
               }
           })
        })
    });
    function authenticate() {
        let data={
            "username": "test",
            "password": "test"
        };
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            $.ajax({
                url:'http://localhost:8000/api/auth/check',
                type:'POST',
                data:JSON.stringify(data),
                dataType:'Json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                resolve(data);
                },
                error:function () {
                }
            })
        });
    }


</script>
```

I added this to debug closely the issue and i found out that this function only executes for `POST` when there's a token method like `OPTIONS` it doesn't execute

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $this->logger->info($event->getRequest()->getRealMethod());
}
```

Comment: Try verifying in a proxy like Fiddler that that the auth header is actually sent.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with proxies can you provide me with a link

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: Thank I've been able to track the request and i couldn't find the token set in the header in the OPTION request, it means there's a problem with client-side right?

Comment: It looks like it - time to degbug that I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days through this, I fixed it by adding to the `CorsSubscriber`

```
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{

    $responseHeaders = $event->getResponse()->headers;
    $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
    $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', ' content-type ,x-auth-token');
    $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET');
    if($event->getRequest()->getRealMethod()=='OPTIONS'){
        $responseHeaders->set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '1728000');
        $event->getResponse()->setStatusCode(200);
    }

}
```

after handling the response I send `200` as status code so I won't have any `CORS` issue

Answer (score 5):

You are making a cross-origin request and adding a non-standard header. This means it is a [Preflighted Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests).

The browser is sending an OPTIONS request to ask permission to make the request with custom headers.

You can't control the format of the preflight request. You definitely can't add credentials to it. (Adding credentials is another thing which turns a simple request into a preflighted request).

You need to response to the OPTIONS request with permission via CORS headers. Since the request won't have any credentials associated with it your server **must not require credentials**.

Change the server to remove the requirement for the credentials when the request type of OPTIONS.

---

I don't know my way around the server-side framework you are using, but extrapolating from the code you've provided I suspect you should provide **separate routes** for GET and OPTIONS.

The OPTIONS request should concern itself *only* with CORS (and not fetch any data which requires authorisation).

The GET request should require authorisation and return the data.

Comment: `Accept */* Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,de;q=0.7 Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-auth-token Access-Control-Request-Method:  GET Connection:                     keep-alive Host:   localhost:8000 Origin:    http://localhost:8080 Referer:                        http://localhost:8080/client.html Sec-Fetch-Mode:                 cors Sec-Fetch-Site:                 same-site` this what the OPTION gets in the header

Comment: @KamelMili — Yes, that's the normal preflight request format.

Comment: And the `Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-auth-token ` is set like suppose to right but after  along debugging I thing the auth guard is blocking the OPTION

Comment: @KamelMili — Well yes. That's why you have *not* apply it for OPTION requests, like I said.

Comment: Thanks for your help, do you have any approaches to solve this, if I understood everything correctly, the auth guard won't allow me to make an auth token so either whitelist the OPTIONS method or probably did the guard and see how solve it